# Where does readstream stores the file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

I read that `createRreadStream` doesn't put the whole file into the memory, instead it works with chunks. However I have a situation where I am simultaneously writing and reading from a file; Write gets finished first, then I delete the file from disk. Somehow, readstream was able to complete reading whole file without any error.

Does anyone have any explanation for this ? Am I wrong to think that streams doesn't load the file into memory?

Here's the code for writing to a file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.createWriteStream('./bigFile4.txt');

function write(stream,data) {
  if(!stream.write(data))
      return new Promise(resolve=>stream.once('drain',resolve));
  return true;
}

(async() => {
  for(let i=0; i<1e6; i++) {
     const res = write(file,'a')
     if(res instanceof Promise)
       await res;
     }
  write(file,'success');
})();
```

For Reading I used this,

```
const file = fs.createReadStream('bigFile4.txt')

file.on('data',(chunk)=>{
  console.log(chunk.toString())  
}) 

file.on('end',()=>{
  console.log('done')
})
```

Comment: Can you post your code maybe so we can try to see what's happening out there?

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: You should read about [`backpressuring`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) in node streams

Comment: @smac89, I am using node version 8.11.3
Also, I read about backpressuring, but couldn't figure out what is helping here. 

I have updated the question(added the code), maybe you can have a look.

Comment: @Mirakurun 
Done

Comment: How do you know that the read stream read all the data? Can you show your full code especially the part that deleted the file that was being written to? Are you running these as two seperate processes or is this being done sequentially? The easiest way to confirm this would be if you piped the read stream to another file on disk (`read_stream_copy.txt`), then instead of deleting the `bigFile4.txt`, give it a different name (which is good as copying the content to a new file and deleting the original), then do a `diff copy_of_bigFile4.txt read_stream_copy.txt`. Paste the output of the diff here

Comment: I'm writing 'a' for one million times, and finally the word 'success'. Once the write is over, I am deleting the file manually, so no code for that. I can confirm that readStream is reading all the data because the last word that get printed is 'success'.

Answer (score 1):

At least on UNIX-type OS'es, if you open a file and then remove it, the file data will still be available to read until you close the file.

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to storing the content of the file in the memory? I'm trying to avoid this situation. Cause with large files, it tends to throw out of memory error

Comment: No, the data is still being read from the file system, it's not stored in memory.

Comment: How does the data is being read from file system if the file itself doesn't exist anymore? Can you explain the working behind it or point me to a resource where I can understand about it more. Thanks

Comment: The [`remove(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) manual page explains it in relatively understandable terms: _"If the name was the last link to a file, **but any processes still have the file open**, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed."_ So even if you can't _see_ the file anymore, it doesn't mean that its data has been removed. It will remain allocated on the file system until the last process is finished with the file.

Comment: Okay. Understood. 
Do you have any idea whether this is the same case for windows operating system also ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Although I seem to remember that on Windows, when a file is still being used, you can't remove it.